# UIScrollView and UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm new to Swift (and programming in general). I'm having some issues getting a Text View to scroll.

I've created outlets for the scroll view and the text view already.

I've found a boat load of people asking the same question on Stack Overflow/Reddit but I am still unable to fix the issue due to just not really knowing what I'm doing.

Here is a screenshot of my view controller so you can see the text I am referring to:

[image]

And here is the code I have in my `viewcontroller.swift` file:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {



    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.descriptionTextView.bounds.size
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

I'm getting the following green error message when I build:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I would love some help from anyone if you are feeling kind or have the time to chime in.

Call me crazy, but would it be silly to believe that it is just overwhelmingly difficult to achieve such a simple thing as scrollable text? I feel like I'm missing something.

Thanks to anyone who may be able to lend a hand.

Comment: `UITextView` will scroll text for you

Comment: The issue is not about scrolling. Is that the full error log?